# Line in Python plot is longer than it should be, overlapping with others

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was plotting some lines as segments of a ring with `plt.polar()` and noticed that they overlap when the radius is too small. So I wanted to take a look at a simpler line plot and this happened:

```py
theta = np.arange(0, np.pi, 0.001*np.pi)
plt.polar(theta, np.full(len(theta), 0.1))
```

[image]

As you can see, the line overlaps with the horizontal axis. How do I prevent that this happens?

Comment: Seems like you don't have a question but just report on how you found your own solution to the problem you were having, to benefit other people who may have the same issue in the future. I suggest you edit your question as an actual question, as if you didn't have the solution yet, following [ask] and [mre]. Then you can answer your own question with all the relevant details * as an answer *, and accept your answer.

Comment: you're right!.. done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that this is happening because if python plots a line from let's say x=0 to x=1 (or in the polar plot: 0 to pi), the line shown in the graph actually goes from sth. like x=-0.01 to x=1.01 because of the extent of the line itself. After looking through numerous websites I finally found on https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html that there is a simple command which makes a line actually end where you want it to:
`solid_capstyle = 'butt'` 
cuts the line at its real end. Just add this to your plot code:

```py
theta = np.arange(0, np.pi, 0.001*np.pi)
    plt.polar(theta, np.full(len(theta), 0.1), solid_capstyle = 'butt')
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot see any difference between the picture in the question and the picture in the answer

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Cannot you see any difference between the picture in the question and the picture in the answer, really?

Comment: the blue region no longer extends below the midpoint